# React Native JS multiple items per array entry

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, react-native

I've set up an array and I'm not sure why I'm getting these results. The array is as follows:

```
var arr = [{0:true,false,false,false},{1:false,true,false,false},{2:false,false,true,false},{3:false,false,false,true}];
```

But a console log output yields the following:

```
{ '0': true, false: false }
{ '1': false, true: true, false: false }
{ '2': false, false: false, true: true }
{ '3': false, false: false, true: true }
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out in the end. It should be like this:

```
var arr = [[true,false,false,false],[false,true,false,false],[false,false,true,false],[false,false,false,true]];
```